# shell script to connect to docker daemon

Tags: shell, docker

I want to easily connect my shell to docker, which I can do so by entering this command:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env docker-vm)"
```

I figured I would put that line in a simple shell script.I find that while the command works by typing the line at the bash prompt, the line will not work if placed in a shell script and then executing the script. After running the script I will receive the error: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

I am using oh-my-zsh and iterm2.

Here is the little script to get the machine running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker-machine start docker-vm
docker-machine ip docker-vm
docker-machine env docker-vm
# this line will not "execute" meaning it does not work from the script
# this line does work proerly when executed from the command line
eval "$(docker-machine env docker-vm)"
```

Comment: Please be more specific than 'is not working'. What behavior do you observe? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1786. `eval "$(docker-machine env --shell bash docker-vm)"`

Comment: That looks like it was fixed in 1.8. I am using docker 1.9. The --shell bash addition has no effect.

Comment: I use the Docker Quickstart terminal that came with the traditional download from Docker's website.  If you did not happen to install that portion, you can see the script here: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/osx/mpkg/quickstart.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh.

For me, I run that script, and then I am golden, no problems.  It sets the environment variables and everything for the bash terminal.  I also put `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` into my .bash_profile so it is in every terminal session.

What is your output from the command `docker-machine ls`?

Comment: @CtheGood yes yes yes that worked great, just copied the script to my own `start.sh` which resides in my docker folder. It probably would be better to have it work every time I open a new `ohmyzsh` window as I am usually doing that to start or connect to a container, which means I need to navigate to the script...

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, note when running a script, it fires a new shell instance and the `eval` command executes on **that instance** which is destroyed when the script exits.

So, you need to run the `eval` on every session.

I suggest you inject the command in `.bash_profile` or similar, so it tries to connect the docker-machine and docker every time. If there is no machine to connect to, it will not, and errors out showing no host is running.

Comment: OK, added `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` into `.bash_profile` ... restart `iterm` and attempt `docker ps` to receive the error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`. Thoughts?

Comment: Ahh modify `~/.zprofile` add in `eval "$(docker-machine env docker-vm)"` then restart `iterm`. Working like a charm. Can you modify your answer to reflect using `oh-my-zsh`? This will help confusion over different shells

Comment: @Iannazzi I did not check this till now, sorry.. anyway, since it's already mentioned "bash profile or similar", I guess people will figure it out.. like you did :)